# Jasper horizontal bar chart data overflowing

Tags: jasper-reports

I have created a jasper report with following xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="SUB_MS_ICM_SUMMERY" language="groovy" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="590" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="0.75"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <subDataset name="incident_category_1">
        <parameter name="start_date" class="java.lang.String">
            <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="end_date" class="java.lang.String">
            <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
        </parameter>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[select category,count from (SELECT  'Total' As category,COUNT(*) as count FROM ms_icm_incident i
where incident_category<>3 and status <> 'Cancelled' and (trunc(nvl(i.initiated_on,$P{start_date})) between to_char(to_date($P{start_date},'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'),'dd-MON-yyyy') and to_char(to_date($P{end_date},'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'),'dd-MON-yyyy'))
union
 select  decode(inc.incident_category,1,'Actual Incident',2,'Near Hit')
 ,count(inc.incident_id) as cnt
 from ms_icm_incident inc
 where inc.incident_category <>3 and inc.status<>'Cancelled'
 and (trunc(nvl(inc.initiated_on,$P{start_date})) between to_char(to_date($P{start_date},'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'),'dd-MON-yyyy') and to_char(to_date($P{end_date},'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'),'dd-MON-yyyy'))
 group by inc.incident_category
 union
 SELECT decode(lov.STORED_VALUE,1,'Actual Incident',2,'Near Hit') as incident_category, 0 as cnt
 FROM ms_local_lov_t lov
 WHERE LOV_NAME='MS_ICM_CATEGORY' and lov.STORED_VALUE <>3
 and lov.STORED_VALUE not in (select  inc.incident_category
 from ms_icm_incident inc
 where inc.incident_category <>3 and inc.status<>'Cancelled'
 and (trunc(nvl(inc.initiated_on,$P{start_date})) between to_char(to_date($P{start_date},'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'),'dd-MON-yyyy') and to_char(to_date($P{end_date},'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'),'dd-MON-yyyy'))))
 order by decode(category,'Total',1 )]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="CATEGORY" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="COUNT" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="incident_severity_1">
        <parameter name="start_date" class="java.lang.String">
            <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="end_date" class="java.lang.String">
            <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
        </parameter>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[select  severity, sum(cnt) from
 (select POTENTIAL_SEVERITY_CALCULATED as severity, count(*) as cnt
                                           from ms_icm_incident where incident_category<>3 and POTENTIAL_SEVERITY_CALCULATED is not null and status <> 'Cancelled' and(trunc(nvl(initiated_on,$P{start_date})) between to_char(to_date($P{start_date},'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'),'dd-MON-yyyy') and to_char(to_date($P{end_date},'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'),'dd-MON-yyyy'))
                                           group by POTENTIAL_SEVERITY_CALCULATED)
dual group by severity
order by decode(severity,'High',1,'Medium',2,'Low',3)]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="SEVERITY" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="SUM(CNT)" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="Incident_status_1">
        <parameter name="start_date" class="java.lang.String">
            <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="end_date" class="java.lang.String">
            <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
        </parameter>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[select status,cnt from (select  status, count(*) as cnt from ms_icm_incident
where incident_category<>3 and (trunc(nvl(initiated_on,$P{start_date})) between to_char(to_date($P{start_date},'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'),'dd-MON-yyyy') and to_char(to_date($P{end_date},'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'),'dd-MON-yyyy'))and status <> 'Cancelled'
group by status
union
select  status, cnt from (select distinct status,0 as cnt from ms_icm_flow_action_status
                                  union
                                  select 'Closed',0 as cnt from dual) where STATUS NOT IN
(select  status from ms_icm_incident
where incident_category<>3 and (trunc(nvl(initiated_on,$P{start_date})) between to_char(to_date($P{start_date},'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'),'dd-MON-yyyy') and to_char(to_date($P{end_date},'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'),'dd-MON-yyyy'))and status <> 'Cancelled'
group by status)and status not in ( 'Cancelled','OHS Investigating','Initiating Incident')
)
order by decode (status,
'Initiated',1,
'Initiated -  Need More Info',2,
'Preliminary',3,
'Investigating',4,
'Draft Report Review',5,
'Final Report Review',6,
'Re-Investigating',7,
'Final',8,
'Closed',9,
'Completed',10)]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="STATUS" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="CNT" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="start_date" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="end_date" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT  'Total' As category,COUNT(*) as count FROM ms_icm_incident i
where incident_category<>3 and (trunc(nvl(i.initiated_on,$P{start_date})) between to_char(to_date($P{start_date},'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'),'dd-MON-yyyy') and to_char(to_date($P{end_date},'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'),'dd-MON-yyyy'))
union
select (SELECT lov.DISPLAYED_VALUE
 FROM ms_local_lov_t lov
 WHERE lov.STORED_VALUE=i.incident_category
 and LOV_NAME='MS_ICM_CATEGORY')as category, count(*) from ms_icm_incident i
 where incident_category<>3 and (trunc(nvl(i.initiated_on,$P{start_date})) between to_char(to_date($P{start_date},'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'),'dd-MON-yyyy') and to_char(to_date($P{end_date},'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'),'dd-MON-yyyy'))
 group by incident_category]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="CATEGORY" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="COUNT" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="505">
            <barChart>
                <chart isShowLegend="false">
                    <reportElement x="15" y="191" width="772" height="280"/>
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <categoryDataset>
                    <dataset>
                        <datasetRun subDataset="incident_severity_1">
                            <datasetParameter name="start_date">
                                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{start_date}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                            </datasetParameter>
                            <datasetParameter name="end_date">
                                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{end_date}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                            </datasetParameter>
                        </datasetRun>
                    </dataset>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{SEVERITY}]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{SEVERITY}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{SUM(CNT)}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                </categoryDataset>
                <barPlot>
                    <plot orientation="Horizontal" labelRotation="0.0"/>
                    <itemLabel/>
                    <valueAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" verticalTickLabels="false" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
                    </valueAxisFormat>
                    <rangeAxisMinValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></rangeAxisMinValueExpression>
                    <rangeAxisMaxValueExpression><![CDATA[$F{COUNT}]]></rangeAxisMaxValueExpression>
                </barPlot>
            </barChart>
            <barChart>
                <chart isShowLegend="false">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="45" width="802" height="113" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <categoryDataset>
                    <dataset>
                        <datasetRun subDataset="incident_category_1">
                            <datasetParameter name="start_date">
                                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{start_date}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                            </datasetParameter>
                            <datasetParameter name="end_date">
                                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{end_date}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                            </datasetParameter>
                        </datasetRun>
                    </dataset>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{CATEGORY}]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{CATEGORY}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{COUNT}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                </categoryDataset>
                <barPlot isShowLabels="true" isShowTickLabels="true" isShowTickMarks="true">
                    <plot orientation="Horizontal" labelRotation="0.0"/>
                    <itemLabel/>
                    <rangeAxisMinValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></rangeAxisMinValueExpression>
                    <rangeAxisMaxValueExpression><![CDATA[$F{COUNT}]]></rangeAxisMaxValueExpression>
                </barPlot>
            </barChart>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="2" y="0" width="795" height="33" forecolor="#FF0000" backcolor="#00CCCC"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="18" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Incident Category ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="1" y="158" width="795" height="33" forecolor="#FF0000" backcolor="#00CCCC"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="18" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Incident Severity]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <summary>
        <band height="507" splitType="Stretch">
            <barChart>
                <chart isShowLegend="false">
                    <reportElement x="4" y="43" width="783" height="404"/>
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <categoryDataset>
                    <dataset>
                        <datasetRun subDataset="Incident_status_1">
                            <datasetParameter name="start_date">
                                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{start_date}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                            </datasetParameter>
                            <datasetParameter name="end_date">
                                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{end_date}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                            </datasetParameter>
                        </datasetRun>
                    </dataset>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{STATUS}]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{STATUS}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{CNT}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                </categoryDataset>
                <barPlot>
                    <plot orientation="Horizontal" labelRotation="0.0"/>
                    <itemLabel/>
                    <valueAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" verticalTickLabels="false" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
                    </valueAxisFormat>
                    <rangeAxisMinValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></rangeAxisMinValueExpression>
                    <rangeAxisMaxValueExpression><![CDATA[$F{COUNT}]]></rangeAxisMaxValueExpression>
                </barPlot>
            </barChart>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="2" y="0" width="795" height="33" forecolor="#FF0000" backcolor="#00CCCC"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="18" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Incident Status]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="0" y="457" width="799" height="50"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["MSI.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Now i am getting the chart as overflown,i have changed the following properties,

Set "Position" to "Float" 
Set "Stretch Type" to "Relative to the tallest object" 
Checked "Print when detail overflows" checkbox. 
But still no help.

my Jasper version is 4.5.0
[image: The First chart Incident Category]

Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Putting `isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"` inside every `reportElement` tag you are using. You have put this in only one of your tag.
Through this the element will be reprinted on the next page if the band does not fit in the current page.

Comment: OP already mentioned that he has enabled that property. `Checked "Print when detail overflows" checkbox`